# Writing a get component method in c++ with templates

Tags: c++, templates, components

I'm trying to write a Unity-style get component method. This is my code so far. It compiles but will return the first component it finds rather than the correct one. I think I'm using static_cast wrong. What is a better way to do this? Note I don't want to hard code component types, I want to be able to compile this engine and use anything that inherits from Component to be able to use this system. Also note that each component needs to return as itself, not a component *, as this would hide child functionality.

compStruct.components is a vector of component *s.

```
template <typename CompType>
inline CompType getComponent()
{
    for(Component * currComp : compStruct.components)
    {
        if (static_cast<CompType>(currComp)!= nullptr)
        {
            return static_cast<CompType>(currComp);
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Here is an example of a generic component

```
#pragma once
#include "Component.h"
#include "Animation2D.h"

class AnimationComponent : public Component
{
public:
    AnimationComponent(GameObject*x) :Component(x) {}
    ~AnimationComponent() {}

    void stepAnimation(double delta);

    //add overload for 3d animations
    int addAnimation(Animation2D);

    void setAnimation(int);

private:

};
```

And the component base class:

```
#pragma once
class GameObject;

class Component
{
public:
    Component(GameObject * h) { host = h; }
    virtual ~Component() {}

    GameObject* getHost() { return host; }

protected:
    GameObject * host = nullptr;
};
```

Comment: You probably want `dynamic_cast`, but that assumes `Component` is polymorphic. Can you provide a [mcve] to be sure?

Comment: Dynamic cast requires the class to be included I'm fairly sure, which wouldn't work in this case as I want to be able to use any component type (again, I think?). I will include MCV example now anyway :)

Comment: You need to cast to pointer, if you want to receive such one; `static_cast` doesn't return null pointer unless the pointer casted already was itself...

Comment: Since we're talking about a function *template*, it's enough to have the class defined when the template is *instantiated* (i.e. when calling the function). I'm pretty sure you will have that covered by the code using it.

Comment: Dynamic Cast fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: @Will Hain dynamic_cast can decrease the performance by a lot if GetComponent is called too many times. If you want fast and constant time querying, I can post a solution that I use for querying components

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`static_cast` is definitely not what you want: it's *static* (compile time), so it cannot determine any runtime information.

What you want is `dynamic_cast` instead. Note that this has several requirements, all of which are fulfilled by your code:

- The classes must be polymorphic. That's covered, because `Component` has a virtual destructor.
- The classes must be defined (not just declared) at the point of the cast. That's covered as well, because `getComponent` is a template and the type in the cast depends on its template parameters (it is one, in fact). Therefore, the definition only needs to be visible where the template is instantiated (i.e. where `getComponent` is called). Since you're presumably doing the casting to access the concrete component's members, you must have its definition visible, so all is well.

Comment: @WillHain Be careful with performance/scalability if you hope to have lots of entities and/or components and do lots of these lookups in common operations. There are more performant ways to structure an ECS depending on needs, but it is hard to give a straight simple answer.

Answer (score 6):

There's some fundamental misunderstanding about `static_cast`: it will just *do* the cast, and it is *your* responsibility to assure the pointer casted actually points to an object of the target type. `static_cast` will only return a null pointer if the source pointer already was itself, but never on type mismatch!

```
class B { /*...*/ };
class D1 : public B { };
class D2 : public B { };

D1 d1;
B* b = &d1;
D2* d2 = static_cast<D2*>(b);
```

`d2` will be a pointer to d1 (in some cases involving multiple inheritance there can be an offset), but interpret the latter's data totally differently (unless `D1` and `D2` are layout compatible) and you might end up in hell!

Now first off, I personally prefer a modified signature:

```
template <typename CompType>
inline CompType* getComponent();
//             ^
```

It allows calling your function like `getComponent<SomeType>()` instead of `getComponent<SomeType*>()`, additionally it allows using pointers inside the function body, which is way clearer, see my my appropriately adjusted code below.

Then what you actually need is a `dynamic_cast` (adjusting your code a little to my personal preferences...):

```
CompType* result = nullptr; // pointer: see above!
for(Component * currComp : compStruct.components)
{
    result = dynamic_cast<CompType*>(currComp);
    if(result)
        break;
}
return result;
```

Edit: Catching up [Nshant Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2717959/nishant-singh)'s comment:

`dynamic_cast` actually is quite expensive.

An alternative could be an `unordered_map`, replacing your vector (example how to set up can be found at [`type_index` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index); of course, you'd place your objects instead of strings...). Then your lookup might look like:

```
auto i = map.find(std::type_index(typeid(CompType));
return i == map.end() ? nullptr : static_cast<CompType*>(i->second);
// now, you CAN use static cast, as the map lookup provided you the
// necessary guarantee that the type of the pointee is correct!
```

Comment: Thanks man. didn't choose as Angew put it first in comment but your explanation has definitely improved my understanding.

Comment: Regarding you note about pointers: nothing prevents the OP from keeping the asterisk out and calling the function as `getComponent<ConcreteComponent*>`.

Comment: @Aconcagua @WillHain I think `type_index` based `unordered_map` would be much faster than the `dynamic_cast` based solution as`dynamic_cast` based solution linearly checks component vector. Also `dynamic_cast` solution can fail if we components have a derivation hierarchy of more than 2 like `Component->AnimationComponent->AdvancedAnimationComponent` and `AdvancedAnimationComponent` is added to the vector before `AnimationComponent`, then `getComponent<AnimationComponent*>` will incorrectly give `AdvancedAnimationComponent`

Comment: @NishantSingh On the other hand, the type index might be a problem if we look up `AnimationComponent`, but only `AdvancedAnimationComponent` resides in the map. Well, we could add the AAC object for both indices (AC and AAC) to solve (or add AAC object only for AC index, if we want to hide it away).

Comment: @WillHain You should only select the *fastest* posted answer out of several, if all of these are equivalently valuable, otherwise, you should select the one you consider answering your question *best*. Well, I don't claim mine to do so in this case, Angew's listing of (covered) pre-conditions is good as well, so your choice is fine, just keep in mind for the future...